# Sidekiq not working properly using apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using apartment gem in one of my projects. And I have a requirement to log one particular type of activity in each of the tenants. For this I created a excluded model, and in the action where the activity happens I added the function to log it. Due to the data I am trying to log, lot of queries are  run when i run this method. Thus i decided to move it to a background worker (Sidekiq). But when the worker runs its saying that its giving errors like.

> Undefined method name for nil class

Now the code which gives this error is `post.author.name`.

This code works properly if we call it directly but breaks when we do it through sidekiq. Has this issue happened to anyone else before? any known solutions?

Worker code is

```
def perform(post_id, subdomain)
  LogTransaction.create_post(post_id, subdomain)
end
```

The LogTransaction.create_post

```
   def self.create_post post_id, subdomain
      post = Post.find(post_id)
      Apartment::Tenant.switch('public')
      create(post_name: post.name, subdomain: subdomain, author_name: post.author.name)
   end
```

Comment: can you post the worker code in the quesiton?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code of the perform function and the class method its calling

Comment: is it possible that one of the `post` that is giving the error doesn't actually have an author? (check if the `author_id` is nil)

Comment: the other guess I have is that the line `Apartment::Tenant.switch('public')` is possibly switching your db schema, and then post.author comes back blank

Comment: Well the author is present for that post. Since I am requesting for `post.author.name` after the tenant switch, could it be loading the author in the public schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this gem in your application, this gem will store which schema from which the job was initiated and it will run in that schema.

https://github.com/influitive/apartment-sidekiq